# HTTP PUT request, how can i generate one and where can i find examples/syntax?

Tags: http, webserver, put

I have an assignment at school to build a webserver that handles GET/HEAD/PUT requests, via browser and Telnet, i have a working server handling GET/HEAD and telnet requests but i cant find out how a put request works/looks. I know its used to put content on a webserver but the syntax i cant find=/

-Jonas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PUT /urlofnewresource HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: xxx
Host: example.org
Connection: close
Any-Other-Header: .. 

Contents. This can be any binary or text file.
```

A response to this (if you created a new resource) may be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
ETag: ".."
Content-Length: 0
```

If you updated an existing resource, it could be

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
ETag: ".."
Content-Length: 0
```

Or just '200 Ok' if you want to return some more information.

This information is not that hard to find though, just look in the HTTP/1.1 specification.

Comment: Thnx for the answer! Im not used to read the HTTP specification, i found the PUT part there: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6, is that the page your refereing to?
How about what program is generating a PUT request? If i want to get a picture PUT, can a Web browser generate it?

Comment: A webbrowser typically does not generate PUT requests, unless you code this with javascript. How you can generate PUT requests yourself depends on which programming language you use.

Comment: I realize that i could generate one myself parsing for example an image to bytes and send it in content but isnt there some program that usally uses a PUT request to upload content in some way?

Comment: Well most REST api's use PUT for updating content, and WebDAV also heaviliy uses PUT.

But it sounds like you're 'looking for a way to use PUT'. Why don't you create a new question that states exactly what your goal is rather than ask these vague follow up questions. It's hard for me to figure out what you're really after this way.

Comment: No, thats true, i will do that =) Thnx alot for the help!

Comment: I just tried "put" command in telnet in CLI, but it returnet "invalid command". How is one supposed to use "put" using telnet?